# Office Add-in TabBar Example

Tags: office-js

I'm looking to add an application-wide top navigation control to an Excel Add-in.  The Office Add-in documentation has a very short description of the recommended way to design navigation and specifies a TabBar as the recommended option:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/navigation-patterns#tab-bar.
But I can't find that control in the Fluent UI documentation.  I only see a sidebar navigation option in the Fluent UI docs.
Does anyone know of an example on adding a top navigation TabBar to an Office Add-in?
Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 1):

How you implement a tab bar depends on what UI framework you are using (e.g., React, vanilla JS, Vue, etc.). Microsoft can't produce implementations for all of them, but they have example implementations in this repo: [Office Add-in Ux Design Patterns Code](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-UX-Design-Patterns-Code).

In particular, see [tab-bar](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-UX-Design-Patterns-Code/tree/master/templates/navigation/tab-bar). There's no JavaScript for that example, but I suspect that the JavaScript for command bar could be adapted: [CommandBar.js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-UX-Design-Patterns-Code/blob/master/templates/navigation/navigation-commands/CommandBar.js).

This add-in uses the tab bar pattern: [Excel-Add-in-JavaScript-SalesTracker](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Excel-Add-in-JavaScript-SalesTracker)

Also, an add-in is basically a web app, so creating a tab bar for an add-in is essentially the same as for any web app. If I search the web for "how to implement a tab bar in a web app?", I get some valuable hits, including [How To - Tabs](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp).